# What does it mean to say that a metal piping system must be "bonded"

Tags: plumbing, electrical-panel, hydronic

What is the physical means by which a metal piping system is "bonded"? Does it mean that it is wired to the grounding bus inside the electrical panel?

If so, should there be such connections between both the copper domestic piping system as well as the black-iron hydronic heating pipe?

Comment: Check the regulations for where you live, they will give you the correct detail. The regs I know for my area may well be different.

Comment: Am I on the right track generally for what it means? It involves attaching the piping system to the panel in some manner? Or ar there other ways?

Comment: You are on the right track.  Unless the two systems are separated by plastic or air, if there is metal to metal connections then should only need to bond one.  Usually the regulations might have.need the bonding a few feet from where the water comes into the house, if used as ground rod.

Comment: I have no idea why people are VtC as a "shopping" question - there is no request here at all for a product or service recommendation. OP is asking about a definition of a process...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ground bonding means connecting something to the Grounding Electrode System of an electrical installation, by means of an effective conducting path, which may mean approved copper or aluminum conductors, but could be metallic clamps, adapters, couplings, etc. Metallic piping systems "likely to become energized" can be connected to any available point on the Grounding Electrode System. This does not mean wired to the breaker panel directly. Every point in the G.E.S., including the breaker panel enclosure and any grounding bars located therein will necessarily be "bonded" together. The usual equipment grounding conductor included in the circuit wires supplying the devices connected to the piping system is a perfectly adequate means of bonding said piping system.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Some years ago we had the panel replaced and the electrician's work was inspected and given a yellow sticker of approval. I do not see any wire going from the panel to any of the metal rods emerging from the ground outdoors. But I do see some heavy gauge wires going from the panel over to the copper water pipes in the basement. Can I assume from this that our system is grounded to the domestic water piping? And does that approach also "bond" the copper piping?

Comment: Or that the *intention* was to ground the electrical to the municipal water. Not asking if it is "safely grounded".